pip version inside virtual environment
I am running a virtual environment:
$ which python
/Users/myself/.venv/bin/python
$ which python3
/Users/myself/.venv/bin/python3
$ which pip
/Users/myself/.venv/bin/pip

To find out the version of pip, if I run python -m pip --version, I get a version number different from what pip --version shows.
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 24.3.1 from /Users/ramepadm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)
$ python -m pip --version
pip 24.3.1 from /Users/ramepadm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)
$ pip --version
pip 24.2 from /Users/ramepadm/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pip (python 3.13) <--- THIS

What could be the reason for this difference?

It looks as if you're running pip from a different virtual environment (note the path reported in the final line of output).
